# Preventing scheduler to use certain cores on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, scheduling

It appears to be possible to pin down a process to a particular core via the `cpuset(1)` utility. It is possible to tell the scheduler to avoid that particular core with all other processes (current and futures ones)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read up on the *old* scheduler in [Process Management in the FreeBSD Operating System](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2249436&seqNum=4)

The "new" [ULE scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ULE_scheduler) was introduced in FreeBSD 5 but was not enabled by default until 7.1. You can find a paper describing it [here](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~roper/ecs150/ULE.pdf). This will give a good understanding of how the scheduler works.

**TIP:** When playing with CPU affinity it is good to know the CPU topology:

```
  $ sysctl kern.sched.topology_spec
```

**TIP:** [procstat](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?procstat) with the -S flag is also help for overview of cpusets used:

```
 $ procstat -a -S
```

And yes - you can tell the scheduler to "avoid" cores by managing the "cpusets". Have a look at the examples in the man page for [cpuset(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cpuset&sektion=1). Cpuset 1 is the default set. You simply modify that set.

From the [man](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cpuset&sektion=1) page:

> Modify the    cpuset all threads are in by default to contain only the
>   first 4 CPUs, leaving the rest idle:
>
> ```
> cpuset -l 0-3 -s 1
> ```

If we imagine we have 8 CPUs we have now moved all threads in the default cpuset to the first 4. As we modified the default set (By default processes are started in set 1) this will now avoid the remaining cores which are left idle.

You could create a new cpuset (ie. number 2) for the remaining CPUs you then assign when you want to use them.